# How to put a new line character in an abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations

I tried the following commands:

```
:abb sm Summary:\n
:abb sm Summary:\\n
```

but it didn't work, nothing escaped, I ended up with the long form instead of a break.

Is there a way to do that from `ex` mode? Is it something with one of those <kbd>^M</kbd> characters? I can't remember how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<cr>` instead of `\n`:

```
iabbrev sm Summary<cr>
```

You use generally use key notation in these cases, something you can find out more about by entering `:h key-notation`.